# Can you communicate with nearby devices using a website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bluetooth, wifi

Can a website help a user communicate with nearby devices via bluetooth/WLAN without downloading software?

1. User requests that something be done on their device (which could be, for example a wirelessly connected printer or a bluetooth keyboard).
2. The site, which contains a repository of relevant actions, sends specific instructions for that device to the user's own machine.
3. Those instructions are then relayed to the correct device (with the user's permission) via the user's device's WLAN or existing bluetooth connection.

Part 3 is what I'm not sure of - is there a mechanism by which a website can contribute to a wireless/bluetooth connection held locally?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/bluetooth ?

Comment: Thanks Brad! I'm looking for something more browser-agnostic but this is good to know about. +1

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. User browser can't interact with hardware for wireless networking.

You should force user to install some custom software to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to submit the "commands" first, then have the device make requests to the website server, i.e., check for any pending "commands" for the device, and then process them locally. A website is not "thing" that can directly interface with a hardware device.